What happens if misconfigured input GPIO delivers 3.3V if it is connected to 3.3V to detect high?
Let's say I have GPIO0 on an ESP32 which is configured as input pin using an external 4.7K Ohm pull-down resistor to ground. Default state therefore is low. When I close the contact, then 3.3V from the ESP32 itself is applied to GPIO0 which pulls the signal up. So far, so good, this should work without any problem.
But what happens if GPIO0 is accidentally configured as output and therefore would deliver 3.3V? Do I need another resistor between 3.3V from the ESP32 and this (potentially misconfigured) GPIO pin?

The situation you described, with the IO configured as an output, and set high, is pictured here:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
There's no conflict here, the MCU effectively connects that output to the +3.3V supply node, and the only significant current flowing will be via the internal pull-down resistor:
$$ I = \frac{3.3V}{4.7k\Omega} = 0.7mA $$
The situation you should avoid is as follows, where the output is set low while SW1 is closed:

simulate this circuit
Here there's a path for current directly from +3.3V to ground, via the MCU output pin. In practice the MCU will have some current limiting, and the actual so-called "short-circuit" current will be somewhat constrained, depending on the model of MCU, but this situation is definitely to be avoided.
You may explicitly limit current in this condition to some reasonable value, using an external resistor:

simulate this circuit
R2 limits the current that will flow:
$$ I = \frac{3.3V}{1k\Omega} = 3.3mA $$
Check your MCU's datasheet to find out what the maximum acceptable sink current is, and choose R2 to stay at or below that value.
The MCU's internal pull-down resistor will influence the potential at the pin when it's configured as an input. R1 and R2 form a potential divider:

simulate this circuit
$$ V_{IN} = V_{DD} \times \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} = +3.3 \times \frac{4.7k}{4.7k+1k} = +2.7V $$
Typically the "high" threshold for CMOS inputs is about 70% of \$V_{DD}\$, which in this case would be +2.3V, and our +2.7V here would be sufficient to register "high". Again, your MCU's datasheet will have information regarding this threshold value.
Choose R2 large enough to stay below the maximum sink current of the IO pin configured as a low output, but small enough that pin potential stays well above the "high" threshold voltage when configured as an input.

If IO pin is set as output and set high to output 3.3V, it only has the 4k7 ohm external resistor to ground as load, and therefore does not output exactly 3.3V due to some voltage drop in the internal structures of the MCU.
When button is pushed to apply 3.3V supply to the output pin, nothing bad should not happen, there should be no dangerous currents to any direction.
However, if the output was set to low, the button would short circuit the output to 3.3V supply, and a lot of current would flow, in some cases even damaging some MCUs.
Same would happen if IO pin outputs 3.3V and button would short it to ground.
Sometimes people put extra series resistors to protect from software mishaps. Sometimes they are omitted because anyone making the code should anyway double-check the usage of important GPIO pins, such as pin direction, initial state of high or low before setting it to output, or deciding use of pull-up/pull-down resistors if pin is an input.

I think I don't understand it correctly, if my example now would be dangerous or not. The misconfigured pin GPIO0, which should be configured as input, but is set as output, being set to low, would short-circuit the other output? So isn't a series resistor between 3.3V and GPIO0 useful in case GPIO0 (still pulled to ground) is misconfigured as output pin?

Your example is dangerous if IO output is low and button forces it high. It is not dangerus if IO output is high and pushbutton also connects it high.

I see. I would prefer to add a series resistor to make it robust against such software errors. Do you think 390R is a good choice?

@Tintenfisch As long as it is not too low or too high, any choise is good, but you need to factor in where in the schematics you will put the series resistor with regards to the pull-down, and are the pin voltages then low or high enough if the two resistors act as a voltage divider. Draw or simulate the schematic variants and calculate voltages and adjust if currents or voltages don't look right.
